# Disqus api, fetching jsonp with jquery returns bad request

Tags: jquery, jsonp, disqus

I need to get some data from disqus, using their api. Normal JSON won't work due to CORS, so I know that I have to use fetch jsonp datatype. However, everytime I try, I get 400 bad request error. Even though when I use the same url manually, there aren't any errors. Do I need any additional headers?

My tries:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?callback=?',
    data: {
        api_key: api_key,
        forum: forum,
        limit: limit,
        include: 'approved'
    },
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log('Fail');
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});

$.get('http://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?callback=?', {
    api_key: api_key,
    forum: forum,
    limit: limit,
    include: 'approved'
}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}, 'jsonp');

$.getJSON('http://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json', {
    api_key: api_key,
    forum: forum,
    limit: limit,
    include: 'approved'
}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Resulting url is always identical:

```
http://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?callback=jQuery11020343882777960971_1385133360572&api_key=XXX&forum=YYY&limit=2&include=approved&_=1385133360573
```

Comment: Are there some stackoverflow-wide javascript coding standards? I never put space between function and opening brackets, and it annoys me a little.

Comment: Without seeing the response, this is a shot in the dark. Two things to check: 1) Are you making the request from a domain you've whitelisted? 2) Have you verified that the forum shortname is valid?

Comment: I've found the culprit - the request requires valid referrer field in headers, and when pushed to a live server everything went just ok.